# angular 4 restrict some special character and zero

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in angular 4 and I am learning to search data from textbox

while I  enter % and some other special characters in my code its create error and my application crash so is there any solution in angular 4.

here is my code

```
 <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                                    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchData" (keyup)="searchItemData(searchData)" type="text" placeholder="Search..."/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Can you share your component file code where the searchItemData function exists

Comment: Also what error you are getting ?

Comment: search item data is making http request for that data there is no other extra logic

Comment: Are you making a get hhtp call with params ? or post http call?

Comment: HTTP POST call with params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this:

```html
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchData" (keyup)="searchItemData(searchData)" onkeypress='return (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123) || (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode <= 31' type="text" placeholder="Search..."/>
```

if you want to restrict more , just add corresponding ascii. otherwise vise versa.

Comment: so I have to set only aski value?

Comment: its up to your requirement. The above code will restrict entering special characters in to input box

Comment: I don't want to restrict  "-" "/ !"

Comment: || event.charCode == 45 || event.charCode == 47 || event.charCode == 33 || event.charCode == 95

Comment: This will allow pasting the special character.